# Function Get User Object By Username?

Tags: plugin-development, users

Which function can be used to get the user's object using the username? I've tried get_userdatabylogin() but the function seemed to throw an error:

Parse error, unexpected T_STRING on line xx

The function was called like so:

get_userdatabylogin($username);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function should do what you want. Are you sure the error is not elsewhere?

You can also try using the [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L161)) function:

`$user = get_user_by('login', 'MaryJane');`

This is the same as `get_userdatabylogin('MaryJane');`